# MongoDB aggregate query return document based on match query and priority values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In a mongodb collection , i have following documents :

```
{"id":"1234","name":"John","stateCode":"CA"}
{"id":"1234","name":"Smith","stateCode":"CA"}
{"id":"1234","name":"Tony","stateCode":"GA"}
{"id":"3323", "name":"Neo","stateCode":"OH"}
{"id":"3323", "name":"Sam","stateCode":"US"}
{"id":"4343","name":"Bruce","stateCode":"NV"}
```

I am trying to write a mongo aggregate query which do following things:

- match based on `id` field
- Give more priority to document having values other than "NV" or "GA" in `stateCode` field.

  If all the document have values either "NV" or "GA" then ignore the priority.
  If any of the document have `stateCode` other than "NV" or "GA" , then return those document.

Example 1:

```
id = "1234"

then return 

{"id":"1234","name":"John","stateCode":"CA"}
{"id":"1234","name":"Smith","stateCode":"CA"}
```

Example 2:

```
id = "4343"

then return

{"id":"4343","name":"Bruce","stateCode":"NV"}
```

Could you please help with a query to achieve this.

I tried with a query , but i am stuck with error:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "input to $filter must be an array not string",
    "code" : 28651,
    "codeName" : "Location28651"
} : aggregate failed
```

Query :

```
db.getCollection('emp').aggregate([{$match:{
            'id': "1234"
        }
},
{
      $project: {
         "data": {
            $filter: {
               input: "$stateCode",
               as: "data",
               cond: { $ne: [ "$data", "GA" ],$ne: [ "$data", "NV" ] }
            }
         }
      }
   }

])
```

Comment: In your 1º example why this document is not returned `{"id":"1234","name":"Tony","stateCode":"GA"}` ?

Comment: @Valijon Because collection contain  documents which does not have value other than "GA"  or "NV"

Comment: If other two document were not present then it should return {"id":"1234","name":"Tony","stateCode":"GA"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually recommend you split this into 2 queries, first try to find documents with a different status code and if that fails then retrieve the rest.

With that said here is a working pipeline that does it in one go, Due to the fact we cant know in advance whether the condition is true or not we need to iterate all the documents who match the `id`, this fact makes it VERY inefficient in the case the `id` is shared by many documents, if this is not possible then using this pipeline is fine.

```
db.getCollection('emp').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'id': "1234"
        }
    },
    {   //we have to group so we can check
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            highPriorityDocs: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$docs",
                    as: "doc",
                    cond: {$and: [{$ne: ["$$doc.stateCode", "NV"]}, {$ne: ["$$doc.stateCode", "GA"]}]}
                }

            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            finalDocs: {
                $cond: [ // if size of high priority docs gt 0 return them.
                    {$gt: [{$ize: "$highPriorityDocs"}, 0]},
                    "$highPriorityDocs",
                    "$docs"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$finalDocs"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$finalDocs"}
    }
])
```

The last two stages are just to restore the original structure, you can drop them if you don't care about it.

Comment: Tried to execute the query and i am getting this error "Unrecognized expression '$nin'",

Comment: sorry i guess you have to wrap it with $expr, ill edit it real quick.

Comment: I ended up replacing it with `$and` and `$ne` as it was the quickest fix and does not really affect anything.